# File and Folder level Permission in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, folder, subfolders

I am working on a live project for an organization and am stuck with file level permission for users.

My scenario for permissions are below:

- I want to create a permission level for document library where users will be able to view the file only neither to read nor to open.
- How to set folder level permission in SharePoint.
  Example: I have created a folder named as Finance and under this have created another Sub-folder Finance Planning and Analysis. Now I have to give permission to certain people to read and edit the sub-folder (FP&A) but not to read the content inside the finance folder.
- How to assign access request level to users to share files with other people.

Hope so my questions are technically existed and will be answerable.

Awaiting your answer.

Regards
Anas

Answer (score 1):

Make them in to separate document libraries.  Make one FINANCE document library and set user's permissions using Groups.  Then make a separate FINANCE PLANNING AND ANALYSIS document library and again set user permission using Groups.

You'll need a naming system e.g. 'Finance 1' for the first finance project, Finance 1 for the next finance project - unless you have a project name you could use instead.

Should you need to link 'Finance 1' together with 'Finance Planning and Analysis' then spend some time familiarising yourself with 'look-up' columns.  These can be used to 'connect' data saved in different places.

Finally, you'll need to customise the navigation bar to make it logical for users.  Add a header called FINANCE PROJECTS, the drop-down bar opens to show Finance Project 1 underneath, to the side you'll see 'Finance Planning and Analysis 1'.  Though if you anticipate that there will be a great many projects coming in the future, then you'll need a different approach to navigation.

**Further Reading / Research**

The SP Maven is a personal favourite of mine for SP Administration - here's a [link to some ideas for setting up document management](https://sharepointmaven.com/configure-sharepoint-document-library/).  You have a few different options, personally I'd probably try and avoid folders (as I've explained above - since permissions will be difficult and confusing to manage).  You could also try using meta-data.

Permissions - [OOTB groups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) - note that many groups are *cumulative* in the permissions they give.  What you suggested in your question might be a custom group OR perhaps 'View' might be the one you need - you'll have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such permission level which is able to view the file only neither to read nor to open.

To set folder level permission in SharePoint, Choose the subfolder-> Shared With->Advanced->Stop Inheriting Permissions->grant the user permission on the subfolder:

[image]

We can only set access request at site collection level, navigate to site settings->Site permissions->Access Request settings->Allow access request:
[image]